# search an array for the existence of another array (array.includes)

Tags: typescript

i have an array of number[] and want to find another array of numbers in this array - or want to know if this array exists in the on big array.

what i tried is this:

```
const polygonBuild = [[
    [
        [0, 0],
        [50, 0],
        [100, 0],
        [100, 50],
        [100, 100],
        [50, 100],
        [50, 50],
        [0, 50]

    ]
]]
const isEndEdge = polygonBuild[0][0].includes([0,0])
console.log(isEndEdge)
```

but it will always console log false. What would be the way to achieve what i need here?

thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific situation I suggest actually comparing the primitive number values of the tuples using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Additionally, you should check for the length of the tuples so things like `[0]` or `[0, 0, 0]` are not considered [*equal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

```js
const polygonBuild = [
  [
    [
      [0, 0],
      [50, 0],
      [100, 0],
      [100, 50],
      [100, 100],
      [50, 100],
      [50, 50],
      [0, 50]
    ]
  ]
]

const target = [0, 0];
const isEndEdge = polygonBuild[0][0].some((a) =>
  target.every((v, i) => v === a[i]) && target.length === a.length);
console.log(isEndEdge)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use includes() to compare arrays, it's actually comparing the references, not the values within the arrays becuase JavaScript arrays are object references.

You can compare arrays of primitive types (like numbers or strings) by using JSON.stringify.

```
const polygonBuild = [
  [
    [0, 0],
    [50, 0],
    [100, 0],
    [100, 50],
    [100, 100],
    [50, 100],
    [50, 50],
    [0, 50],
  ],
];

const isEndEdge = polygonBuild[0][0].some(
  (arr) => JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify([0, 0])
);

console.log(isEndEdge);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "*includes*" method checks each element of the array for equality with the specified value and returns true if it finds a match; otherwise, it returns false.

You can also use includes with arrays of non-primitive types, like objects, but keep in mind that **it checks for reference equality, not structural equality.**

You should write bit more code:

```
function isSubarrayContained<T>(subarray: T[], arrayOfArrays: T[][]): boolean {
    // Iterate through the array of arrays
    for (const array of arrayOfArrays) {
        // Check if the subarray is equal to any array in the array of arrays
        if (arraysAreEqual(subarray, array)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

function arraysAreEqual<T>(array1: T[], array2: T[]): boolean {
    // Check if the arrays have the same length
    if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Check if every element in both arrays is equal
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
};

const polygonBuild = 
[
    [
    [
        [0, 0],
        [50, 0],
        [100, 0],
        [100, 50],
        [100, 100],
        [50, 100],
        [50, 50],
        [0, 50]

    ]
    ]
];

var firstLevelNest = polygonBuild[0];
var secondLevelNest = firstLevelNest[0];
var thirdLevelNest = secondLevelNest[0]

console.log(firstLevelNest);
console.log(secondLevelNest);
console.log(thirdLevelNest);

var arrayToCompare = [0, 0];

var areEqual = arraysAreEqual(thirdLevelNest, arrayToCompare);
var isIncluded = isSubarrayContained(arrayToCompare, secondLevelNest);

console.log(areEqual); //=> will print true
console.log(isIncluded); //=> will print true
```